# Ordered combinations

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 2 sets of elements, say $\{A, B, C, D\}$ and $\{P, Q, R, S\}$, how can I calculate combinations of combined set $$\{A, B, C, D, P, Q, R, S\}$$ such that order $A\to B\to C\to D$ and $P\to Q\to R\to S$ is maintained in each combination.

For example $$\{A, B, C, D, P, Q, R, S\},\\\{A, P, Q, R, B, S, C, D\}, \\\{P, Q, R, S, A, B, C, D\}\hphantom{,}$$ are **valid** combinations whereas 
$$\{A, B, C, D, Q, P, R, S\}, \\ \{A, B, D, C, P, Q, R, S\}\hphantom{,}$$ are **invalid**.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Once you know which 4 positions $A, B, C, D$ are in, how many possible ordered combinations are there?

Comment: Got it. It's basically C(8, 4).